# get second ID from array

Tags: php, functions, meta-query

I need to get the second attachment ID from this function and put it into a separate custom field:

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'replace_thumbnail', 10, 3);

function replace_thumbnail($id) {
$image_ids = array();
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $id );;
foreach($media as $item)
$image_ids[] = $item->ID;
$image_ids_str = implode(',',$image_ids);
update_post_meta( $id, '_easy_image_gallery', $image_ids_str );
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

I know how to change it to the custom field I want, just not how to single out the second or third ID.

I've tried putting numbers between the square brackets in the $image_ids, but that didn't do anything. clueless where to start with this one.

I tried adding a stop on the third foreach loop.

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'replace_thumbnail', 10, 3);
function replace_thumbnail($id) {
$image_ids = array();
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $id );
$i=0;
foreach($media as $item){
$i++;
if($i==3) break;
}
$image_ids[] = $item->ID;
$image_ids_str = ($image_ids);
update_post_meta( $id, 'test_id', $image_ids_str );
}
```

Comment: In what context? Are you trying to hack that function? Are you needing to pull the post meta somewhere else and extract that data?

Comment: Yes I'm needing to pull the attachment ID from URLs being passed through the function being imported by XML data, on the way through I need to separate the second or third ID to be used as the post thumbnail, the software has the option to import the first automatically, but in this instance it really isn't suitable.

Comment: There are no URLs being passed anywhere in that code. You've now made things more confusing.

Comment: The URL import is being done by the software before this function, once imported it fetches the attachment ID sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is called "replace_thumbnail" so I am assuming you are trying to set/replace the post thumbnail (featured image):

```
function replace_thumbnail($id) {
  $image_ids = array();
  $media = get_attached_media( 'image', $id );;
  foreach($media as $item) {
    $image_ids[] = $item->ID;
  }
  // insert your featured image
  if (!empty($image_ids[1])) {
    update_post_meta( $id, '_thumbnail_id', $image_ids[1] );
  }
  // 
  $image_ids_str = implode(',',$image_ids);
  update_post_meta( $id, '_easy_image_gallery', $image_ids_str );
}
```

You can use any other key besides `_thumbnail_id` if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to skip the first ID and get the second, do I just change the 1 's to 2's

Comment: The first id is `0`. That is basic PHP. PHP like most programming languages enumerate starting from `0`. That means that the second id is `1`.